# show some tables content in real-time

Tags: sql-server, real-time, tableau-api, olap

I use **Tableau** application for getting **OLAP** from my database (MS SqlServer). it so good and work perfectly! after that, we decide to show some tables content in real-time for the user. (tableau is not real-time tools and cant do that). is there any application for this purpose?

To avoid develope an application I prefer to use tools like Tableau for this purpose! is there any software?

Comment: Tableau does supports live connection to data sources. Not sure what do you mean by real-time.

Comment: real time duration you are planning to show data?